# Resource loading in external jars not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm making a game using LWJGL and Slick2d, and naturally have game assets to export in my jar to use.  However, they fail to load from within the runnable .jar I create using jarsplice, but *will* run when they are in the same folder as the .jar file.  I am attempting to use .getSystemResource() and .getSystemResourceAsStream() to load the files in the source code within Eclipse to solve this issue, but it will not work.  I've spent hours searching through stackoverflow, gamedev.net, lwjgl forums, and slick2d forums for loading resources in jars exported from Eclipse, to no avail. Here's the process I go through:

1) I configure my build path - everything is included, nothing is exluded.

2) all libraries are correctly added;

3) everything is selected for ordering and exporting.

4) I export as a general (non-runnable) .jar, deselecting those folders and packages that are not referenced by my code.  Those folders containing my audio, images, and shaders are correctly marked for exporting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj4Pt.jpg

5) I open the .jar file, and everything is inside as it should be.  At this point, the manifest file is empty.

6) I create a fat .jar using jarsplice, first adding the .jar files;

7) next I add all the natives required by lwjgl;

8) finally I enter in my main class using the full package path.

9) when I create the .jar and look inside, everything is included as it should be.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMH7B.jpg

additionally, the manifest file is now correctly filled out:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Launcher-VM-Args: 
Launcher-Main-Class: com.fafnir.gestalt.Bootstrap
Main-Class: org.ninjacave.jarsplice.JarSpliceLauncher
```

10) upon running the .jar using 'java -jar FatRunnable.jar' I receive errors, so I create a .bat file to run it and log the output in a text file:

```
java -jar FatRunnable.jar %* > log.txt
PAUSE
```

11) I check the text file and see the following:

```
Wed Jul 30 17:42:11 EDT 2014 INFO:Initialising sounds..
[LWJGL] getPathFromClassLoader: searching for: OpenAL32
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.URLClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.security.SecureClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] getPathFromClassLoader: searching for: lwjgl
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.URLClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.security.SecureClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] getPathFromClassLoader: searching for: lwjgl
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.URLClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.security.SecureClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Found 6 OpenAL paths
[LWJGL] Testing 'C:\Users\MOTHAF~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\natives-1942957663\OpenAL64.dll'
[LWJGL] Found OpenAL at 'C:\Users\MOTHAF~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\natives-1942957663\OpenAL64.dll'
[LWJGL] MemoryUtil Accessor: AccessorUnsafe
Wed Jul 30 17:42:11 EDT 2014 INFO:- Sound works
Wed Jul 30 17:42:11 EDT 2014 INFO:- 64 OpenAL source available
Wed Jul 30 17:42:11 EDT 2014 INFO:- Sounds source generated
[LWJGL] Initial mode: 1600 x 900 x 32 @60Hz
[LWJGL] Found 32 displaymodes
[LWJGL] Removed 20 duplicate displaymodes
Detected display modes:
800x600x32 60Hz
1600x900x16 60Hz
640x480x16 60Hz
1024x768x16 60Hz
1280x720x32 60Hz
1280x800x16 60Hz
800x600x16 60Hz
1600x900x32 60Hz
640x480x32 60Hz
1024x768x32 60Hz
1280x720x16 60Hz
1280x800x32 60Hz
[LWJGL] GL_EXT_direct_state_access was reported as available but an entry point is missing
OpenGL version: 3.2.9712 Core Profile Forward-Compatible Context
Could not read file.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: glsl\textured.vs (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:87)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.quads.QuadUpdateVBO.loadShader(QuadUpdateVBO.java:180)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.quads.QuadUpdateVBO.setupShaders(QuadUpdateVBO.java:146)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.quads.QuadUpdateVBO.<init>(QuadUpdateVBO.java:49)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.Bootstrap.setupArtists(Bootstrap.java:167)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.Bootstrap.<init>(Bootstrap.java:72)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:38)
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Could not locate symbol glEnableClientStateiEXT
Could not locate symbol glDisableClientStateiEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetFloati_vEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetDoublei_vEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetPointeri_vEXT
Could not locate symbol glNamedCopyBufferSubDataEXT
Could not locate symbol glVertexArrayIndexOffsetEXT
Could not locate symbol glVertexArrayVertexAttribOffsetEXT
Could not locate symbol glVertexArrayVertexAttribIOffsetEXT
Could not locate symbol glEnableVertexArrayEXT
Could not locate symbol glDisableVertexArrayEXT
Could not locate symbol glEnableVertexArrayAttribEXT
Could not locate symbol glDisableVertexArrayAttribEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetVertexArrayIntegervEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetVertexArrayPointervEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetVertexArrayIntegeri_vEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetVertexArrayPointeri_vEXT
Could not locate symbol glMapNamedBufferRangeEXT
Could not locate symbol glFlushMappedNamedBufferRangeEXT
```

12) it would seem that, despite the shaders being in the .jar file, it cannot find the shaders located in the 'glsl' folder.  From what I gather, this is because they are not seperate files but located within the .jar, and must be accessed using different code.

The shaders are being loaded by passing the path to the files, along with the GL20 value, to my loadShader(String fileName, int type) method:

```
// Load the vertex shader
vsId = loadShader("glsl/textured.vs", GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

// Load the fragment shader
fsId = loadShader("glsl/textured.fs", GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
```

13) the loadShader method which worked in eclipse but not for the .jar was as follows:

```
public static int loadShader(String fileName, int type) {
    final StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    int shaderID = 0;

    try {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not read file.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
    GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
    GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);

    if (GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        // Check for any OpenGL errors
        OpenGLHelper.exitOnGLError("Error in quads.QuadUpdateVBO.loadShader()");
    }

    return shaderID;
}
```

14) I have attempted to change it to use the ClassLoader so that it will work with resources packed inside of the .jar, but I cannot even get it to work in eclipse.  This is my new method:

```
public static int loadShader(String fileName, int type) {
    final StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    int shaderID = 0;

    try (InputStream shaderStream = QuadUpdateVBO.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shaderStream))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not read file.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
    GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
    GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);

    if (GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        // Check for any OpenGL errors
        OpenGLHelper.exitOnGLError("Error in quads.QuadUpdateVBO.loadShader()");
    }

    return shaderID;
}
```

and here is the output to my Eclipse console upon running my Bootstrap class:

```
Wed Jul 30 17:58:02 EDT 2014 INFO:Initialising sounds..
[LWJGL] getPathFromClassLoader: searching for: OpenAL32
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:     java.net.URLClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:     java.security.SecureClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] getPathFromClassLoader: searching for: lwjgl
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:     java.net.URLClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:     java.security.SecureClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] getPathFromClassLoader: searching for: lwjgl
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:     java.net.URLClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Failed to locate findLibrary method: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:     java.security.SecureClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
[LWJGL] Found 14 OpenAL paths
[LWJGL] Testing 'C:\Program Files\eclipse\external jars\LWJGL     2.9.2\native\windows\OpenAL64.dll'
[LWJGL] Found OpenAL at 'C:\Program Files\eclipse\external jars\LWJGL     2.9.2\native\windows\OpenAL64.dll'
[LWJGL] MemoryUtil Accessor: AccessorUnsafe
Wed Jul 30 17:58:03 EDT 2014 INFO:- Sound works
Wed Jul 30 17:58:03 EDT 2014 INFO:- 64 OpenAL source available
Wed Jul 30 17:58:03 EDT 2014 INFO:- Sounds source generated
[LWJGL] Initial mode: 1600 x 900 x 32 @60Hz
[LWJGL] Found 32 displaymodes
[LWJGL] Removed 20 duplicate displaymodes
Detected display modes:
800x600x32 60Hz
1600x900x16 60Hz
640x480x16 60Hz
1024x768x16 60Hz
1280x720x32 60Hz
1280x800x16 60Hz
800x600x16 60Hz
1600x900x32 60Hz
640x480x32 60Hz
1024x768x32 60Hz
1280x720x16 60Hz
1280x800x32 60Hz
[LWJGL] GL_EXT_direct_state_access was reported as available but an entry point is     missing
OpenGL version: 3.2.9712 Core Profile Forward-Compatible Context
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.quads.QuadUpdateVBO.loadShader(QuadUpdateVBO.java:194)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.quads.QuadUpdateVBO.setupShaders(QuadUpdateVBO.java:147)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.quads.QuadUpdateVBO.<init>(QuadUpdateVBO.java:50)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.Bootstrap.setupArtists(Bootstrap.java:167)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.Bootstrap.<init>(Bootstrap.java:72)
    at com.fafnir.gestalt.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:38)
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Could not locate symbol glEnableClientStateiEXT
Could not locate symbol glDisableClientStateiEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetFloati_vEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetDoublei_vEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetPointeri_vEXT
Could not locate symbol glNamedCopyBufferSubDataEXT
Could not locate symbol glVertexArrayIndexOffsetEXT
Could not locate symbol glVertexArrayVertexAttribOffsetEXT
Could not locate symbol glVertexArrayVertexAttribIOffsetEXT
Could not locate symbol glEnableVertexArrayEXT
Could not locate symbol glDisableVertexArrayEXT
Could not locate symbol glEnableVertexArrayAttribEXT
Could not locate symbol glDisableVertexArrayAttribEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetVertexArrayIntegervEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetVertexArrayPointervEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetVertexArrayIntegeri_vEXT
Could not locate symbol glGetVertexArrayPointeri_vEXT
Could not locate symbol glMapNamedBufferRangeEXT
Could not locate symbol glFlushMappedNamedBufferRangeEXT
```

Comment: 1st: TMI 2nd: is the shader file lying next to the QuadUpdateVBO class in the jar?

Comment: No, the QuadUpdateVBO was in 'com.fafnir.gestalt.quads,' while the shader file was in 'glsl/'

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a robust way to answer my own problem - by creating a new class called 'ResourceHandler' I set up a few methods to take Strings as parameters, along with a boolean value (to indicate whether or not it was being loaded in the style of .getSystemResourceAsStream() or not) and spit out either BufferedReaders, InputStreams, or Audio objects, which work both in Eclipse and packed within a Fat .jar from using jarsplice.  here's the code for the class:

```
package com.fafnir.gestalt.helpers;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.newdawn.slick.openal.Audio;
import org.newdawn.slick.openal.AudioLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class ResourceHandler {

/**
 * Returns a buffered reader of the input file from a (non/)streaming resource
 * 
 * @param filePath
 * @param streaming
 * @return
 */
public static BufferedReader loadIntoBufferedReader(String filePath, boolean streaming) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    if (streaming) {
        InputStream stream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(filePath);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
    } else {
        URL url = ResourceLoader.getResource(filePath);

        try (FileReader freader = new FileReader(url.toURI().toString())) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(freader);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.err.println("File " + filePath + " does not exist!");
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (URISyntaxException urise) {
            System.err.println("Bad URI syntax for " + filePath + "!");
            urise.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("File " + filePath + " couldn't be read/written to!");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    return reader;
}

/**
 * Returns an InputStream of the input file
 * 
 * @param filePath
 * @return
 */
public static InputStream loadIntoInputStream(String filePath) {
    InputStream stream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(filePath);
    return stream;
}

/**
 * Returns an Audio object of the input file as a stream
 * 
 * @param type
 * @param filePath
 * @return
 */
public static Audio loadIntoAudio(String type, String filePath, boolean streaming) {
    Audio audio = null;
    try {
        if (streaming) {
            audio = AudioLoader.getStreamingAudio(type, ResourceLoader.getResource(filePath));
        } else {
            audio = AudioLoader.getAudio(type, ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(filePath));
        }
    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("File " + filePath + " couldn't be read/written to!");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return audio;
}
```

}